# How to set QAction icon text

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I'm learning PySide6 and I want to set the icon text for a QAction.

This is what I tried:

```
    button_action = QAction(self)
    button_action.setIcon(QIcon("chain--arrow.png"))
    button_action.setIconText("Chain") # This does not seem to work
    button_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+T')
    button_action.setStatusTip('Test application')
    button_action.setToolTip('Tooltip')
    button_action.triggered.connect(self.onMyToolBarButtonClick)
    button_action.setCheckable(True)
```

Is there something similar to setToolButtonStyle() method of QToolBotton() class for the QAction class?

[image]

Comment: Since you're using a QToolBar, have you read its documentation? Specifically, the part regarding the [tool button style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbar.html#toolButtonStyle-prop)?

Comment: Ciao, grazie :)